# jQuery .slideToggle() - slide upper down

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I created a slide out impressum with jQuery [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```
jQuery("#impressum").slideToggle();
jQuery(this).toggleClass("open");

// just a smooth slide down 
var theOffset = jQuery("#impressum").offset();
jQuery('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: theOffset.top -150
}, 1000);
```

HTML dummy:

```
<div class="impressum-wrapper">        
<div class="center">        
    <div class="impressum-button" id="drawers">
        <h5 class="accordion">Impressum</h5>
        <div class="show-impressum">
            image with arrow down
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="impressum"> 
CONTENT             
</div>
```

Problem (in Chrome and Internet Explorer (firefox works fine)):

the impressum is at the bottom of the page. When the impressum
is folded again, the animation runs and leaves a whitespace, after the animation the page resizes to the new size and the view jumps up.

Is there a way to avoid the whitespace?
Alternative: can I make the animation runs from the top to bottom (currently bottom to top)?

Greetings
Rob

Comment: can you share your CSS too ? so we can accurately replicate your problem ? or better a snippet or fiddle

Comment: Could you please provide us with a jsfiddle